# Block Java Code until Object Animator finished in Android

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am very new on the Andorid Programming. I would like to block my Java code until object animator finished. For example, I am translating a image inside a function which is PlayAgents. In normal execution, java code is continuing to work.

PlayAgents();

for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            .
            .

In the example above, java code needs to wait end of PlayAgents function which is responsible for translating the images using Object Animator.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an animation listener to your object animator like this

```
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Write your for loop here
        }
    });
```

And then write your for loop in `onAnimationEnd()`;

Comment: checkAnimation = 0;
playAgents();    
while(checkAnimation == 0);

I am declaring checkAnimation as global inside activity class. Firstly, I assing checkAnimation to 0 then I assign it to 1 inside the onAnimationEnd function. After calling the function I am waiting using the while loop. However; It enters an infinite loop. Also I checked that it assigns the checkAnimation to 1.

Is there easy way to implement it in this way? I don't want to disrupt the order of my code.

Comment: I am try with this object ObjectAnimator animator , but this object not has the setAnimationListener methode